# PHP page times out - can I resolve via asynchronous display?

Tags: php, asynchronous

I have a PHP page that sends notification emails. When it sends out more than ~100 it times out. I'd like the page to work like Kayak so that the user can see progress occurring (so they will wait longer).

How can my page quickly load (preventing timeout) before sending the emails, then update as and when the process runs (e.g. as each email is sent a line gets written to the screen)?

Comment: With AJAX. And preferably not PHP on the server side. Something like this really needs a worker thread - maybe you could mimic this with [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) but it wouldn't be easy - you would be better starting a worker process, then polling a database with AJAX for progress updates.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with AJAX. Send an AJAX-request that sends out 50 (or any other number that fits into the timelimit) and echos out the result. When the request successfully finished send out the next AJAX-Request with a parameter called offset, that will be used to skip the first X datasets.

Comment: Thanks - AJAX spans a bunch of technologies - can you be more specific - I'm assuming you're suggesting Javascript. Any pointers to sample code or routines to achieve what you describe/that are more specific immensely appreciated to illustrate your answer.

Comment: I thought of something like this: https://gist.github.com/1582933, the JS is an jQuery AJAX-Request, i assume it is possible to understand anyway. The code was not tested working, but it should give an idea how to do.